# How to show another form inside MDI parent form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my scenario. I have a login form, once I login next will show the main form. But I cant show the second form inside MDI parent form.

Login form code:

```
MainMenu b = new MainMenu();
  
b.Show();    
this.Hide();    
var f = new SubMain();    
f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;    
f.Show();
```

Comment: Have you set "IsMidiContainer" on your parent form to True?

Comment: Yeah, I already set in True, I get your point, but the problem is I can't show 2 forms at a time after I run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>> But I cant show the second form inside MDI parent form.**
What is your MDI parent form? Or what is the MDI parent window of the login form
I made a test with you code, and set Form1's IsMidiContainer to true.
Here is my test code:
Form1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    login.MdiParent = this;
    login.Show();
}
```

Login form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenu b = new MainMenu();

    b.Show();
    this.Hide();
    var f = new SubMain();
    f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    f.Show();
}
```

The result:
[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7khtU.gif)

Best Regards,

Daniel Zhang